# Does Neovim or any of its GUI variants have the option to be embedded in a GUI window?

Tags: neovim, window-management, embedded, gui

Emacs has the ability to be embedded in a GUI window using the `--parent-id=xid` option where `xid` is an X Window handle.

So I have created GUI programs in which I can embed an Emacs session for improved editing.

Does Neovim or its variants have similar options?